# LiveAgent Custom Chat Code

Tags: apex, soql, liveagent

Can we access Chat Button Code based on Button Id or Button api name in Live agent . The Button code which is automatically created for us by Salesforce.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can query the object LiveChatButton.

Select DeveloperName From LiveChatButton

**UPDATE:** I misunderstood the question. To answer, no, you cannot obtain this code other than from the UI as is not exposed though any API.

I can't think why you would want to do that, but technically speaking, if REALLY wanted to do this, you would be able to programmatically reconstruct the code generated by getting the button ID and the image ID, which is stored in a static resource, and using string concatenation...of course, this is a silly idea.

Comment: It Will give me the Button API name . I need the Chat Button Code . The Code which is auto-generated by Salesforce . You can see this under .. Setup-> Chat Buttons -> Open any Button --> Scroll down to bottom .. You see the code.